# Gutenberg block previews suddenly not working

Tags: block-editor

I have an issue with the Gutenberg block previews suddenly not showing at all when hovering over available blocks in the side panel. I have tried:

- Commenting out custom code in the `functions.php`, including removing
  any enqueued JavaScript and CSS from the admin
- Deactivating plugins (such as Advanced Custom Fields)

But the preview popup is still not showing. It worked initially, but right now it's not working at all. I can't see any errors in the JavaScript console or by enabling debug in the `wp-config.php`.

The expected behaviour would be for each block to show a preview and a description of the block that you're hovering, but that popup is not showing as it is now. See this image for how it should look like:

[image]

I've tried searching for this on Google, but I can't find anyone else having this problem. Has anyone here had this problem and knows what was causing it? Or is it a problem occurring because of a bug in Wordpress itself?

Comment: Seems like this has to do with the update of Wordpress version 5.6.1 where this functionality breaks. Found this issue over at Github:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/28823

Comment: You can install the Gutenberg plugin, enabling that will enable a more recent version of the Block Editor that is shipped with Core. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem for now. Don't know how good it is to use a beta for production, but it'll probably work. Thanks!

Comment: It is not beta. You can opt in to use experimental features, otherwise it is just a more recent version than is shipped with Core right now. What you'll have with the plugin, you'll have with WP core - just a few months later.